# How to add a text to the remaining text in android

Tags: java, android, string

I want to add text to the EditText without losing the previous text.

**Ex:** when typing `74`, i want to add the `"4"` to the text box without erasing the number `"7"` entered before.

```
public void add4()
{   
    res = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    if(res.getText().toString() == "0")
    {
        res.setText("4");
    }
    else
    {
        // add number 4 to the remaining string
    }       
}
```

Comment: use `append` instead of `settext.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.append("4");` or you can use `res.setText(res.getText() + "4");`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `append` method to append to existing text.

```
res.append("4");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)

(As a side note, don't use `==` to compare strings, use `.equals()`)

Comment: And I hope you don't mind that I add a side note here. To avoid `NullPointerException`, you should always run `.equals` on the object you are sure it's a string... like `"0".equals(res.getText().toString())`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

I used the `.equals` method on a string object to avoid the `NullPointerException` that may happen if the object is null or not a string.

```
public void add4() { 

    res = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    if( "0".equals(res.getText().toString()) )
    {
        res.setText("4");
    }
    else
    {
        res.append("4");
    }       
}
```